# Django Spreadsheet Application

Tags: django, excel

I am in the making of a Django application where you will be able to upload an excel spreadsheet file and have it inserted into the application. But I sorta got the importing  sorted out.

What I need is a way to store the values dynamically, I basicly need X number of fields for each row, with each three possible types.

These would be:

- Boolean
- String
- Number

How would I go about doing so?
Let's say I have some models that contains this information:

A spreadsheet with a name, and some "header"-cells that will indidate which fields (and their name) that belong to that spreadsheet (but dynamically expanding).

A row that can have multiple cells, each with a type of either a boolean, a string or a number.

An example could be like this:

**Spreadsheet 100**

- name (string)
- city (string)
- religious? (boolean)
- phonenumber (number)

and then I need to pair the cells underneath with the appropiate header, like this:

**row**

- name = "Bob Curious"
- city = "New York"
- religious = "Yes"
- phonenumber = "888 888 888"

I hope that explains it good enough, if not, please go ahead and ask for anything you might like explained.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

This post is pretty old so I'm not sure whether you still need help with your issue, but I've found [xlrd](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html) to be an excellent tool for scraping spreadsheet data.  I would suggest investigating this package further.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe others would like to hear more about the solution for this question. My plugin [django-excel](https://github.com/chfw/django-excel) would help with excel [data import](http://django-excel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#handle-data-import) into and [export](http://django-excel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#handle-data-export) from one or more django models. What's more, the plugin provides one programming interface to handle data in ods(using odfpy or ezodf), xls(using xlrd), xlsx(using openpyxl) and csv formats. I hope it may help you.